# HTML CSS Image on top of another but the image behind has mouse priority

Tags: html, css, image, cursor

I have this problem when creating a website,I have image A on top of Image B,but when I hover with mouse and press it I want to react as I pressed on Image B.Is it possible or should I crop the images accordingly?
Thank you in advance!
P.S. If needed I can attach images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make pointer-event: none for Image A as follows

**CSS**

```
imageA {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Changed pointer-events: none;

Check fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fxww4r3h/

I am applying actions to `.imageB`, when it is placed under `.imageA`